# How can I loop through an array to pull out an Id number javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list that is coming from the db and creates a list of checkbox inputs. When the user clicks on the checkbox it will populate only that item. What I want to do to begin with is check the status of the checkbox. If it's checked I want to console.log the systemId and the operator name to compare to make sure they match.
here is my code:

```
        $(".wellProducer").click(function(){
            if(this.checked == true){
                console.log(wells["SystemId"]);
                console.log(wellProducers["Operator"]);
            }
        });
```

The .wellProducer is the class of the input checkbox. What I have populating right now is all the systemId's and operators, but I want to compare them to see if they match.

Comment: Do you want to compare each element of the first array and see if the equal to every element of the second one?

Comment: @nicovank yes I do.. I want to see if SystemsId = Operator.. and the ones that equal each other, then console.log them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < wells.SystemId; i++) {
    if (wells.SystemId[i] == wells.Operator[i]) {
        console.log(wells.SystemId[i]);
    }
}
```

Asuming they are strings, and that they are put in the same order. Otherwise comment this answer and I'll see what I can change to make it work.

Comment: how do I check the status of the check box to see if it's been checked, then run this?